# Return NaN with statistics.mean() when passed empty list

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if this is an appropriate question, but I was wondering what the best (simplest?) way to do this is.

I want to return a `NaN`(not a number) value when I pass an empty column (or string) to the `statistics.mean()` function in Python. So, something like:

```
variable_mean = statistics.mean(data[column_name])
```

I want the `variable_mean` variable to equal the mean when the `pandas` dataframe has data points and `NaN` when it is empty (I have a for loop and each iteration has dataframes with different numbers of rows, sometimes there are no rows).

Maybe I just need to do like:

```
if len(data) == 0:
   variable_name = float('nan')
```

But it seems like there must be a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it return now if the input is empty?

Comment: I get the following error: `StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `mean` of non numeric / empty values fail, so use `try-except` statement:

```
def check(data, column_name):
    try:
        return statistics.mean(data[column_name])
    except:
        return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,6],
                   'b':list('abc')})

print (check(df, 'a'))
3
print (check(df, 'b'))
nan

print (check(pd.DataFrame(), 'b'))
nan
```

Comment: Ahh okay, nice, yeah that looks pretty good! Was wondering if it could be done in one line or something. But this is a good solution - thanks for the help!